# Cannot read property 'errorCallback' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use a Factory in a way which allows me to run a function but I cannot seem to get it working.

In my controller I want to call `httpErrorHandler.statusHandlerFunction.errorCallback()`

This is my Factory:

```
  .factory('httpErrorHandler', ["Restangular", "StorageService",
        function (Restangular, StorageService) {

            return statusHandlerFunction = function errorCallback() {
                return alert("Oops error from server :(");
            }

        }]);
```

I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property `errorCallback` of undefined

I have also tried:

```
.factory('httpErrorHandler', ["Restangular", "StorageService",
    function (Restangular, StorageService) {

        return function errorCallback() {

            return alert("Oops error from server :(");
        }


    }]);
```

but get : undefined is not a function

UPDATE

Thanks for answers. Helped me a lot ended up with this:

```
.factory('httpErrorHandler', function (Restangular, StorageService) {
    return {

        errorCallback: function () {
            return  alert("Oops error from server :(");
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your object notation. Try this:

```
.factory('httpErrorHandler', ["Restangular", "StorageService",
function (Restangular, StorageService) {

  var factory = {
    statusHandlerFunction: {
      errorCallback: function () {
        return alert("Oops error from server :(");
      }
    }
  }

  return factory;

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not got that return statement quite right. Try this:

```
.factory('httpErrorHandler', ["Restangular", "StorageService",
    function (Restangular, StorageService) {

       var exports = {}

       exports.errorCallback = function() {
                                  return alert("Oops error from server :(");
                              }
       return exports;


    }
]);
```

Call it with this instead:

```
httpErrorHandler.errorCallback();
```

That way is it's easier to read, you can keep adding methods to your exports object and return it at the end.